# Stuck outside MySQL / XAMPP

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have been using XAMPP (on Windows XP/XAMPP 1.7.4 /PHP 5.3.5) for quite a while now, and last morning I started to get some weird messages when I was developing my website. It happened yesterday and started as something I thought I could handle but apparently I couldn't. These messages were some about timeouts, some were about "can't connect" for my connection string inside my website.

I was thinking that the site might be under attack as last morning was pretty much like any other morning. I can actually start the admin (the button near the "start/stop" apache) page, but can't login to MySQL. I think root was not set, so I tried to use the documentation to reset it.

What happens now is that I just can't login into MySQL Server no matter what I do. I keep getting access denied for ''@'localhost' and 'root@localhost' if I try logging as root.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to restart mysql from the Linux command line like this:

```
service mysql restart --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking
```

If you are using Windows, add the two options in the mysqld section of my.ini:

```
[mysqld]
skip-grant-tables
skip-networking
```

and then run

```
net stop mysql (wait 10 seconds)
net start mysql
```

This will allow immedidate login without authentication and without any remoye connection sneaking in on you.

```
INSERT INTO mysql.user SET
Host='localhost',
User='mynewuser',
Password=PASSWORD('whateverpassword'),
Select_priv='Y',
Insert_priv='Y',
Update_priv='Y',
Delete_priv='Y',
Create_priv='Y',
Drop_priv='Y',
Reload_priv='Y',
Shutdown_priv='Y',
Process_priv='Y',
File_priv='Y',
Grant_priv='Y',
References_priv='Y',
Index_priv='Y',
Alter_priv='Y',
Show_db_priv='Y',
Super_priv='Y',
Create_tmp_table_priv='Y',
Lock_tables_priv='Y',
Execute_priv='Y',
Repl_slave_priv='Y',
Repl_client_priv='Y';
```

then

```
service mysql restart
```

At least you will have a localhost user named `mynewuser` with enough privileges to login.

You should then run this query:

```
select user,host,password from mysql.user;
```

and see if any new users were added by a hacker. If you see any remote users that should not be there, you can remove them with:

```
DELETE FROM mysql.user WHERE ...;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

If you are using Windows, please remember to remove `skip-grants-tables` and `skip-networking` from my.ini, then stop and start mysql service.

**CAVEAT**

Make a backup of `/var/lib/mysql/mysql` before you do anything.

**UPDATE 2011-09-26 10:41 EDT**

If the INSERT INTO mysql.user query does not work, it simply means the query is not compatible with the version of mysql I took this example from.

In order to know the correct INSERT query to user, please run this query:

```
desc mysql.user;
```

You will see all columns with the type ENUM('Y','N') for each privilege. Adjust the INSERT query to match all columns and then run that INSERT.

To get the exact columns to set to Y for all privileges, user this query:

```
SELECT CONCAT('SET ... ',GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(column_name,'=''Y'''),';'))
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema='mysql'
AND table_name='user'
AND column_type='enum(''N'',''Y'')'
ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION\G
```

This will present to columns to set regardless of the version of MySQL you are using.

Comment: ok, so right after your paragraph **"This will allow immedidate login without authentication and without any remoye connection sneaking in on you."** I get this "ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)" as I tried logging in with **mysql -u root**

Comment: @Ted : just type 'mysql' and hit enter. If you added the two options into my.ini and restarted the mysql service, you should get the mysql prompt immediately.

Comment: ok, just typed the mysql, pasted in the UPDATE command and got this: **"ERROR 1142 (42000): INSERT command denied to user ''@'localhost' for table 'user'** (which I always get)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1441/discussion-between-rolandomysqldba-and-ted)