# Resetting MySQL Password

Tags: mysql

Please see the following link from Super User. I cannot get anything working:

> https://superuser.com/q/342609/93569

**Update: This link has been dramatically changed! Please see the link.**

Comment: I have posted an answer at the link you have provided. Check it out.

Comment: I posted what to do with the InnoDB log files

Comment: not a fan of the way this quesiton was asked. I'm not going to click a link to superuser to read a question.

Comment: If the OP or anyone else wants to edit the question to be an actual question and have this question reopened, they are welcome to, however, this is not acceptable, never has been on the Stack Exchange network, and is generally answered at the provided link, thus requiring no or little input here.

Answer (score 1):

On Debian or Ubuntu you can also do this on the command line to login as the administrator:

```
sudo mysql --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf
```

Then you reset the password as randy has indicated.

Comment: I'm using Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Your innodb_log_file_size is set incorrectly, so InnoDB isn't starting up.  You haven't even gotten to the part where the password reset would matter.

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple if you can restart your MySQL daemon.

Simply add 'skip-grant-tables' to your mysql configuration file (*nix: /etc/my.cnf).
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_skip-grant-tables

Then, get into mysql:

```
mysql -u root
```

Next, reset your password:

```
SET PASSWORD FOR user = PASSWORD('Passw0rd');
```

Finally, remove the 'skip-grant-tables' from your configuration and restart mysqld.

For an extended level of verbosity, see Rolando's answer:
[Stuck outside MySQL / XAMPP](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6168/stuck-outside-mysql-xampp-help-please/6172#6172)

Answer (score 0):

I have posted an answer at the link you have provided, with the following info:

In your case, before you can even reset the password, you need to fix the start up issue.

Note the first error listed in MySQL error log:

```
InnoDB: Error: log file .\ib_logfile0 is of different size 0 5242880 bytes
InnoDB: than specified in the .cnf file 0 24117248 bytes!
```

This means that you may have copied your database files from another location or you have edited my.cnf settings and they no longer match the real ib_logfile0 file size. Focus on this issue first.